# How can I add a GET param to some anchor elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of `a` elements and I want to add a GET param to their `href` attribute.

I want to use `?` or `&` where appropriate.

For example, `http://example.com` should become `http://example.com?extra=true` and `http://example.com?already_got_a_param=true` should become `http://example.com?already_got_a_param=true&extra=true`.

What code would do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this...

```
$('a').attr('href', function(index, href) {
    return href + (this.search ? '&' : '?') + 'extra=true';
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKfma/).

Comment: +1 for using `.search` instead of trying to parse it out of the `.href`.

Comment: @Shad: They actually mention it in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *"It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! – phrase it in the form of a question."* :o)

Comment: @patrick ty for the info, i had never expanded that section of the faq =)

Comment: @patrick If you can come up with anything better, post it. I often find even better ways to do things when playing *Jeopardy!* on here. :)

Comment: Well, if it was me, I'd probably stick to updating the `.search` property directly instead of using `.attr()`. http://jsfiddle.net/hKfma/2/ I never feel like I know if `.attr()` is operating on the *attribute* or the *property*. But really it's just a minor variation on your answer.